# Using ActiveSupport::Concern and create accessors and validations dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to use `ActiveSupport::Concern` in order to extend the `ActiveRecord::Base` funcionality, dynamically.

So I have a class (in `app/models/foo.rb`)

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

and in `lib/activ_record_extention.rb` I have

> ```
> module ActiveRecordExtension
>
> extend ActiveSupport::Concern
>
>     module ClassMethods
>
>        c= atrr_name
>        attr_accessible c.to_sym
>
>
>
>     end 
>
> end
>
>  ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
> ```

But when I run the server I get :

```
undefined method `attr_accessible' for ActiveRecord Extension:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: You have to put it into `included` block and it will work. I guess because, `ActiveRecordExtension` doesn't know anything about `attr_accessible`.

Comment: Thanks @Magnuss, But where to put the `included` block?

Comment: You can check it out at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html . Replace the `module ClassMethods` with `included do`

Comment: hanks @Magnuss. One more thing.. may you tell me how do I get the module name within the `includeed` block ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
module ActiveRecordExtension
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessible # Still need to call the API method

    def mass_assignment_authorizer
      # Here we can access object's attributes
      super << some_attr 
    end
  end 
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

I updated my answer.

Comment: My `:some_attr` are in a table, and I want them to show only in the current module, so I need the module name inside the block. how to do it?

Comment: I updated answer, but I don't seem to understand what do you mean by _module name inside the block_. What exactly is _module name_?

Comment: Verry appriciated @Magnuss.

Comment: Very appreciated @Magnuss. I have a Table where I keep my accesible attributes. And I want that each module will get his own accesible attributes. for example: In my AccessibleAttributes I have Table + attribute, and in my include block I want to use somthing like:
`AccessibleAttributes.where(name: "#{self.name}").each do |e| attr_accessible e.attribute.to_sym
end` but `"#{self.name}"` dosnt work...

Comment: I added clearer question (I hope) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27892104/3385098)

Comment: I eventually realized that the solution is not using ActiveSupport :: Concern but writing code in a different way.
Thank you!