# How to get my model name within an ActiveSupport::Concern included block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using `ActiveSupport::Concern` to extend `ActiveRecord` funcionality, to DRY my modules. But in order to do so, I need the module name of my `ActiveRecord` inside `included` block.

For example,  I have a Table where I keep my accesible attributes, And I want that each module will get his own accesible attributes

My `module ActiveRecordExtension` look like:

```
module ActiveRecordExtension

    extend ActiveSupport::Concern


        included do
            AccessibleAttributes.where(name: "#{self.name.pluralize}").each do |e| 
               attr_accessible e.attribute.to_sym 
            end
        end 


    end

    # include the extension 
    ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include, ActiveRecordExtension)
```

A. How do I get my model name (dynamically) without getting `nil:NilClass` ?

B. And how do I check what `included do` returns ?

Comment: I don't think you can with your current setup - included is called when the module is included, ie at the point when you call `ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include,...)`. I don't think it will be called again for individual subclasses.

Comment: Thanks, @Frederick. Let me explain. I have a Table where I keep my accesible attributes. And I want that each module will get his own accesible attributes. for example: In my AccessibleAttributes I have Table + Attribute, and in my include block I want to use somthing like: `AccessibleAttributes.where(name: "#{self.name}").each do |e| attr_accessible e.attribute.to_sym end` but "#{self.name}" dosnt work...

Comment: I eventually realized that the solution is not using ActiveSupport :: Concern but writing code in a different way.
Thank you!

Comment: If you remember from all these years ago @David I would love to get a message on what you did. Having trouble organising something similar with Serializers and a concern to generate dynamic methods for timestamp attributes